# How to configure CAS AuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, configuration, servlet-filters, cas

According to the [CAS Java Client config guide](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+Jasig+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml) you need to add an `AuthenticationFilter` to `web.xml` which will attempt to send all HTTP requests on to the CAS server.

**But what if I only want certain URLs authenticated?** What if `http://myapp.com/aboutUs` doesn't require any authentication at all? Of course, if the user goes to `https://myapp.com/login`, then yes I want the `AuthenticationFilter` to kick in. But there are definitely some requests that I don't want auth for.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict what urls the filter is enabled for, you can use the standard web.xml filter property when defining the filter: `<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>`